# ¿Como añado una variable en location.replace de Javascript usando c# y selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

Seguro que es la mayor estupidez o cosa más sencilla del mundo, pero no caigo en ello, quería saber, usando C# y Selenium, con `IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;` quería saber como puedo añadir una url que paso como parametro a %url%.

```
js.ExecuteScript("window.location.replace('%url%')");
```

Espero haberme explicado correctamente.

Esto es lo que he probado

```
        public static void urlChange(string url)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)internet;
        String javascript = "window.location.replace('"+url+"')";
        js.ExecuteScript("window.location.replace('%url%')");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, necesitas cambiar la URL de la página actual.

Puedes hacerlo ejecutando Javascript tal como tu lo pones en tu ejemplo:

```
public static void urlChange(string url)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)internet;
    js.ExecuteScript("window.location.replace('" + url + "')");
}
```

También podrías utilizar las funciones que te da el mismo Selenium:

```
public static void urlChange(string url)
{
    internet.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
```